# Is there a way we can capture a column value from first row and assign it to next few rows in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am relatively new to Pyspark and trying to figure out a way to do the following. I have a file which contains different record types(1,2,3 etc) and only record type 1 contains the key or in this case the name of the patient. I want the Name of the patient to be added to all the record types in record set.

Input file:

- RCD_TYPE_1,John Smith,100,USA,NY,1st street
- RCD_TYPE_2,Caucasian,5 ft 10 in, Married, Male
- RCD_TYPE_3,Tylenol, Claritin
- RCD_TYPE_1,Amy Smith,50,USA,NY,1st street
- RCD_TYPE_2,Caucasian,5 ft 1 in, Married, Female
- RCD_TYPE_3,Ibuprofen, Benadryl
- RCD_TYPE_4,Thyroxin, Panadol

Desired output:

- RCD_TYPE_1,John Smith,100,USA,NY,1st street
- RCD_TYPE_2,John Smith,Caucasian,5 ft 10 in, Married, Male
- RCD_TYPE_3,John Smith,Tylenol, Claritin
- RCD_TYPE_1,Amy Smith,50,USA,NY,1st street
- RCD_TYPE_2,Amy Smith,Caucasian,5 ft 1 in, Married, Female
- RCD_TYPE_3,Amy Smith,Ibuprofen, Benadryl
- RCD_TYPE_4,Amy Smith,Thyroxin, Panadol

Is there any existing functionality in pyspark that can help do this?

Comment: If you can have input in other format, i.e. json, then it's possible. If all the data appears as in your example, it's hard to match data. You may need to split the input file to multiple files, one per person.

Comment: Could you provide all the input data to support your output?